# PHP post Rest API

Tags: php, rest, post, restful-url

I'm searching all day long what's happen with my api call from php page but can't find a working solution.
Simple, I have one rest api which needs 2 parameters, it returns a json message.
Calling the api from postman for example, it works fine.
Calling from my php page, it blocks my webserver until timeout raises.

my block is (one of found here on SO):

```
        $url = HOST . '/users/verifyemail';
        $userID = $_GET['userID'];
        $key = $_GET['key'];            

        $postdata = http_build_query(
            array(
                'userID' => $userID,
                'apiKey' => $key
            )
        );              

        try
        {

            $opts = array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $postdata
                )
            );
            $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

            $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
            if ($response) {
                echo "OK";
            } else {
                echo "NOK !";
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }
```

Even the catch isn't called.

In my webserver I have this:

```
[Wed Jun 17 20:39:18 2015] ::1:52312 [200]: /emailValidation.php?userID=16&key=1212
[Wed Jun 17 20:39:18 2015] ::1:52313 [200]: /users/verifyemail
```

As everything was fine...

[My PHPInfo](http://www.loffreda.com.br/phpinfo.html)

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: What is your constant HOST and what is the "output" of $url

Comment: HOST = 'http://localhost:8000. $url = http://localhost:8000/users/verifyemail'

Comment: yes. Even placing my index.php/. There are no errors at all.

Comment: Are you using the php build in command line stuff, and not using apache or something like that

Answer (score 0):

please try php-curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "$url",
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        userID => "$userID",
        apiKey => "$key",
    )

));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

[image: phpinfo output]

Comment: $response always false and my webserver gives me [Wed Jun 17 21:00:26 2015] ::1:53447 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

Comment: Ok, are you running Apache2?

Comment: MacBook-Air:etc user$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
Server built:   May 19 2015 16:46:25

Comment: Ok, I see. How did you install php and are you running php5? You must have php5-curl installed to make a curl request.

Comment: Could you please make a sample php file and add this into it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Then go to that page with your browser and see if you can find a separate box, which heading is "curl". Edited the screenshot into my post.

Comment: Ok, if it's still not working, I'll check it tomorrow. I've been using that exact curl for Google's captcha and for me it works fine. But I'm running Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's not working, I'm trying everything but no success. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Kasper Franz was right.
Even having PHP installed as third part in my mac, it was using the built-in instance and the problem was about the single thread.

Changing the configuration resolved the issue.

Thank you AirPet for your prompt help too ;-)